# Change Nagios email From name

Tags: email, alert, nagios

With Nagios email alerting, I'm looking to have the email From address and name look something like

```
John Doe <username@hostname.com>
```

Currently it looks like `username@hostname.com`.

I would have thought that in `define contact` the `alias` line would have inserted the real name in addition to the email address, but that doesn't appear to the case.

Any thoughts on how to modify the Nagios email alert to include the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined user name (comment) in /etc/passwd? AFAIK sendmail uses it.

see `man -S5 passwd`

Answer (score 0):

This was annoying me also, with more than one nagios server, and all emails arriving from "nagios", so I did as explained above, and edited the

/etc/passwd file like such

replace this below line
nagios:x:102:112::/var/lib/nagios:/bin/false

with
nagios:x:102:112:Donald Duck Nagios:/var/lib/nagios:/bin/false

and now my emails appear from "Donald Duck Nagios".